# option clash for package biblatex

Tags: latex, bibliography

I can't print Bibliography no matter how I try. Currently I use 
this code :

```
\bibliography{biblio} 
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}  

\begin{document}

        \input{conclusion}
        \clearpage

              %\bibliography{biblio.bib}
                \printbibliography

                \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliographie}
                \clearpage
        \input{annexes}
        \clearpage

    \backmatter
        \input{./tpl/resume}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is better asked on the [TeX SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/). See if [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13509/biblatex-in-a-nutshell-for-beginners) helps.

Comment: Without knowing the options loaded with your example code (either as part of `\documentclass` or other packages), it's impossible to answer your question.